# AWS Amplify and AppSync custom domain

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have created and associated a custom domain name to access my AppSync API using the web interface. When I run amplify pull and regenerate the aws-exports.js file the aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint does not reflect the custom domain name. How can i make it refer to my custom domain without modifying it by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS Support have said that this is currently not possible using the Amplify CLI